# fade in and out when hovering

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
   <title>Instagram Search</title>
   <style>
        header {
height: 30px; 
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
top: 0;
}

.main {
margin-top: 70px;
}
body {
background-image: url("black-texture-wallpaper-background-wood-backround-wooden-wood1.jpg");
}
.img{
    border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #fff;
     height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
    @font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(Cash_Currency.ttf);
   }
   h1{
    font-size: 4em;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px #fff;
            font-family: myFirstFont;

} 

   </style>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.lamia.byethost18.com/get_info.php",
                    data: {keyword: $("#keyword").val()},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: 
                        function(jsonStr) {
                        $('#name').text($("#keyword").val());
                        var all_results = '';
                        $.each(jsonStr.data, function(index, element){
                            all_results += '<div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">';
                            all_results += '<img class="img" src="'+element.profile_picture+'" />';
                            all_results += '<p align="center"> @' + element.username + '</p>';
                            all_results += '</div>';
                        });
                            $('#images').html(all_results);
                        }
                });
            }); 
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#images img').css('opacity', 0.4);  

   $('#images img').hover(  
   function(){  
  $(this).fadeIn('slow');  
 },  
  function(){  
   $(this).fadeOut('slow');  
  });  

   }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header style="margin-bottom: 1cm; ">
        <div style="float:left;" align="left">Instagram User Explorer</div>
            <div align="center">
                <form name="contact" id="contact" method="get">
                Search : <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"/>
                <input type="button" value="search!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
    </header>

    <section class="main">
        <h1 id="name" align="center"></h1>
        <div id="images"></div>
    </section>

</body>

   </html>
```

Which retrieves from `php` file some pictures and display it. I want to use `jquery` to fade in and out pictures when hovering in and out.

I tried the `jquery` above but this will fade in and out all of the retrieved pictures at once. How to do it so it will be on one picture at time ?

Comment: Do you have multiple images in `#images` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have tagged this question with `css`, I would suggest a css-only solution. You don't really need jQuery/Javascript for this.

Just use `transition` on the images.

***See this snippet:***

```css
#images .img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 750ms all;
}

#images .img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
 <div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" />
  <p align="center">Username 1</p>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/63/63" />
  <p align="center">Username 2</p>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/65/65" />
  <p align="center">Username 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

### Update:

If you only want to use jQuery, you can make it simpler by still using a class and then assigning it on hover. Not many changes.

***See this snippet:***

```js
$("div#images").on("mouseenter", ".img", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
});

$("div#images").on("mouseleave", ".img", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

```css
#images .img {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: 750ms all;
}

#images .img.hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
 <div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" />
  <p align="center">Username 1</p>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/63/63" />
  <p align="center">Username 2</p>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left; margin-left: 100px;" class="result_row">
  <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/65/65" />
  <p align="center">Username 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

***And a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/py8ydLx4/***

### Update 2:

If you still want to use jQuery `fade` only, then all you have to do is, this:

```
$("div#images").on("mouseenter", ".img", function(e) {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 1);
});

$("div#images").on("mouseleave", ".img", function(e) {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("normal", 0.3);
});
```

***And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/py8ydLx4/2/***

### Note:

*I would strongly recommend using CSS transition instead of jQuery animations because CSS transition are far more efficient than jQuery animations.*

Comment: thank you so much for this !! but i have to do it with jquery .. sorry i tagged css by mistake.. can you tell me how to do the same thing with jquery ??

Comment: @lama: There... updated the answer with a jQuery version! I would still recommend strongly for CSS based transition because it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have multiple images in #images so change your hover condition to `#images img`

```
$('#images img').hover(  
     function(){  
  $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);  
     },  
    function(){  
       $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.4);  
      });  

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#images img').css('opacity', 0.4);  
 $('#images img').hover(  
     function(){  
  $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
     },  
    function(){  
       $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.4);  
      });
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: it will stop working when i put '#images img' i dont know why

Comment: yeah your code is working perfectly fine .. but why its not working with me ?? :(

Comment: @abhitalks answer worked perfectly with me .. your code is working too and correct but i dont know why its not working with me ... Thank you so much for the help !! :)

Comment: Great! You got answer! Keep coding!